# What is the best way to propagate child state updates upward in react

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I have this structure:

```
function ParentComponent() {
    const [editedData, setEditedData] = useState<any[]>([])
    return <ChildComponent data={editedData} />
}
function ChildComponent(props: {data: any[]}) {
    // ...
}
```

Inside of `ChildComponent` the `data` is displayed in a grid that can be modified by `ChildComponent`. When a button is clicked in `ChildComponent`. When these modifications happen, I would like `ParentComponent` to get the updated data from `ChildComponent`

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
function ParentComponent() {
    const [editedData, setEditedData] = useState<any[]>([])
    function onItemEdited(items: any[]){
        setEditedData(items);
    }
    return (
        <ChildComponent
            data={editedData}
            onItemEdited={onItemEdited}
        />
    )
}
function ChildComponent(props: {
    data: any[],
    onItemEdited(data: any[]): void
}) {
    // ...
    onItemEdited(newData) // doing when I need to update
    // ...
}
```

So in `ParentComponent` I always have an up-to-date version of `data` and then when I need it I can use it.

But I have  a feeling that it is not the best way to do that. Basically I have a parent component, it has some data that I pass to a child and then the child can modify it but I want the updates to propagate up to the parent I would like to be able to mutate the data in the child component.

Would that be the best approach to achieve what I described?

The case is that I have a main component, it gets some data from server, and I push it into a reusable grid component, then the user can modify whatever they want and then if there is an action in main GoToNextStep (it is wizard with many steps), the edited version of data would be sent to server and this is handled in the Main (Parent) component.

Comment: If the state is managed in the parent component and the child component needs to use and update that state, passing the state and an updater function to the child component is exactly how one would do that.

Comment: What you described is the proper way of doing it. See https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The approach you are using sounds correct to me. You may consider using some kind of global state management or context if you want to avoid prop drilling as things get large. Also I edited your question feel free to edit it if I lost any meaning or anything I just tried to make it more coherent

Comment: You can pass the "set state function" of `useState()` from the parent to the child, but that gives the child component 100% control of the state variable.  Using a function the way you show in your example allows the parent some control over whether what the child component is doing is okay...you could put validation checks or other types of business logic in the function that you pass down to the child.  If you were building your parent component as a type of library or module, using a function the way you have done is the better way to go, enabling validation and permission checks to happen.

Comment: From what you described, I think your way is not wrong, but since these data will be used in many steps, maybe you can put them in a global state manager(there are many of them: https://fe-tool.com/awesome-react-state-management), then share it in all your steps' component